# How to toggle a dom audio element

Tags: javascript, audio

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to allow a user to toggle all sound on or off by button press. I have created the function to toggle the audio:

```
function playPause(id){
soundElement = document.getElementById(id);
if (soundElement.pause) {
    soundElement.play();
}
else
    soundElement.pause();
}
```

Then the code to function on keypress:

```
 if (keys.hasOwnProperty(77)){
 soundElement.playPause();
 }
```

I have several pieces of audio that run through soundElement. Do I have to loop through all of soundElement to allow the user to mute all audio or is there a way to pause all of soundElement without having to loop every id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` instead:

```
var audioElements = document.querySelectorAll("audio");
```

Then iterate each one and toggle the state, for example:

```
var i = 0, el;
while(el = audioElements[i++]) playPause(el);

function playPause(soundElement) {
   if (soundElement.paused) {
     soundElement.play();
   }
   else
     soundElement.pause();
}
```

To check for pause state use `paused` instead of `pause` (the latter being a method).

Just note that there is no guarantee that an audio is playing/has loaded etc. so some error-checking is needed to make this work flawlessly.